# How to prove that $L(I)=m(I \setminus A)+m(A)$?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $A$ be any subset of $\mathbb R$ and let $I$ be any compact interval of $\mathbb R$ containing $A$

Then I need to prove that 
$$L(I)=m(I \setminus A)+m(A)$$ where $L(I)$ denotes the length of $I$ and $m(A)$ denotes the outer measure of $A$

All I know regarding this problem is, if $F$ is collection of subsets of $\mathbb R$ such that $A$ is in $F$ if $m(A\cup B)=m(A)+m(B)$, where $B$ is any subset of $\mathbb R$ such that $A\cap B = \varnothing$, then this collection contains all intervals.

Comment: Since the '\' character is used as a delimiter for $\LaTeX$ commands, an empty '\' does nothing but put a blank space between characters. If you want a backslash to appear in math mode, do \setminus. It's a very common mistake to make, but a mistake that is easily avoided.

Comment: This is false. Assuming the axiom of choice, there is a subset of the unit interval such that both it and its complement have outer measure $1$.

Comment: In fact, if I'm not mistaken, this statement is true iff $A$ is a measurable set.